# Web View Display "Android WebCore is not supported in this case" Warning

Tags: android, webview

webView.load(url) is not loading the web page (previously it is).
When I checked the android logs ,found this warning message :

```
WebCore is not supported in this case Warning.
```

Has any one faced this issue?

Comment: what version sdk of android? what configuration webview? Any important information?